# CURL vs allow_url_fopen Which is safer for getting images?

Tags: php, security, curl

I have a script that users can input a image URL (from another website) and then crop it using JS and have it saved on my server.

My question is... when getting the image from another server is it safer to use CURL or allow_url_fopen (via file_get_contents())? Or is there a preferred/safer method available?

Security is a big concern for me as I know this is a very dangerous procedure - The script will only need to work for image files if that makes a difference.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

curl's error handling is much better than `file_get_contents()`. If you care about that, curl's probably the way to go. If a simple "oops, that didn't work" is enough for you, though, `file_get_contents()` is a perfectly acceptable shortcut.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, if you want to get into a deep security discussion. Downloading files is in fact a security concern if you don't know what you are doing.

You can overwrite vital files or even overwrite system files in some cases. Uploading scripts,etc on the server with intention of executing them via web server is also an issue.

So it's not sunshine and rainbows like people pointing out here.

Back to your question, allow_url_fopen is a configuration directive. I assume you meant [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file_get_contents.php). Either will do fine. As others pointed out Curl is a bit more verbose and it's also faster.

If you do end up using file_get_contents(), make sure you never include an unfiltered variable as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Downloading a file is not a security concern at all, no matter whether it's your server or your own computer, or the application/code you are using to download it :) It's whether you are executing the file :D

All you have to do is just make sure you are not going to EXECUTE / INCLUDE anything in the file. Since you are only going to crop the image, I think you are good to go :)

I suggest cURL tho, allow_url_fopen may raise security problems in other places in your code.

Answer (score 0):

cURL has more options ans possibilities.

Both are equally safe (or unsafe if misused).

It is wiser to use cURL because you will uprise your experience with a more powerful function, which may serve you in future projects.

Also, if this very project needs new functionalities later on, you will not have to rewrite everything with cURL if file_get_contents is not enough.

The answer of this thread shows a nice cURL function: [Replace file_get_content() with cURL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11920026/replace-file-get-content-with-curl)

Answer (score -2):

curl would generally be a safer way. It'd take an explicit design/coding decision on your part to allow the results from curl to directly affect your program, whereas allowing urls in the f*() functions would let

```
include('http://example.com/really_nasty_remote_takeover.php');
```

occur without error.

Comment: `include()` is controlled by the more restrictive `allow_url_include`, not `allow_url_fopen`. Using `file_get_contents()` is harmless.